# Error when querying in IBM Content Navigator

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet-process-engine, ibm-content-navigator

We are using the IBM Content Navigator 2.0.3 with IBM FileNet P8, Version 5.2. We want to make a query according the [Process Engine REST Service Reference](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.2.0/com.ibm.p8.pe.dev.doc/rest/rest_ref.htm). I made an appointment for the columns in a given basket (according [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/pt-br/SSNW2F_5.2.0/com.ibm.p8.pe.dev.doc/rest/rest_ref.htm#rest_ref__Workbasket_Columns)) and I made this query:

```
[ECM SERVER]/CaseManager/P8BPMREST/p8/bpm/v1/queues/SPLN_Autuacao/workbaskets/Autuacao/columns?cp=CP1
```

My result was this (showing just 2 columns):

```
{
    ...,
    "SPLN_itemkey":{
        "ordinal":2,
        "prompt":"itemkey",
        "attributes":"queues\/SPLN_Autuacao\/workbaskets\/Autuacao\/columns\/SPLN_itemkey\/attributes",
        "sortable":false,
        "type":2,
        "name":"SPLN_itemkey"
    },
    "SPLN_actid":{
        "ordinal":3,
        "prompt":"actid",
        "attributes":"queues\/SPLN_Autuacao\/workbaskets\/Autuacao\/columns\/SPLN_actid\/attributes",
        "sortable":false,
        "type":1,
        "name":"SPLN_actid"
    },
    ...
}
```

If I make a query with no parameters like

```
[ECM SERVER]/CaseManager/P8BPMREST/p8/bpm/v1/queues/SPLN_Autuacao/workbaskets/Autuacao/queueelements?cp=CP1
```

Some results I get are:

```
{
    "lastRecord":null,
    "queueElements":[
        {
            "lockedBy":"",
            "stepProcessorId":165458,
            "milestones":"queues\/SPLN_Autuacao\/stepelements\/942CF4FC538FDC46A9E3ADBE3CF607C1\/milestones",
            "caseTaskId":"{C087B74F-0100-C29D-9C14-EB557CC6F2D6}",
            "stepElement":"queues\/SPLN_Autuacao\/stepelements\/942CF4FC538FDC46A9E3ADBE3CF607C1",
            "canReassign":true,
            "boundUserName":"",
            "ETag":"14313.0",
            "stepDeadlineStatus":0,
            "stepName":"020 Autuacao",
            "workObjectNumber":"942CF4FC538FDC46A9E3ADBE3CF607C1",
            "caseFolderId":"{C087B74F-0000-C51C-8788-3E63307F980B}",
            "queueName":"SPLN_Autuacao",
            "lockedById":0,
            "columns":{
                "F_StepName":"020 Autuacao",
                "SPLN_resultout":"COMPLETE: ",
                "F_CreateTime":"2015-09-10T13:52:53Z",
                "F_Subject":"Fluxo Autuacao",
                "SPLN_funcmode":"PR_ELABORACAO:FN_ST_ELABORACAO",
                "SPLN_IDDocumento":"1098857",
                "SPLN_itemkey":"620006",
                "SPLN_itemtype":"SPL",
                "SPLN_actid":null,
                "SPLN_Natureza":"Mo\u00e7\u00e3o"
            }
        },
        {
            "lockedBy":"",
            "stepProcessorId":165458,
            "milestones":"queues\/SPLN_Autuacao\/stepelements\/9E1DCCF25AEE4A4FA4C61421214B9F40\/milestones",
            "caseTaskId":"{008DB74F-0100-C600-9410-D38352275E36}",
            "stepElement":"queues\/SPLN_Autuacao\/stepelements\/9E1DCCF25AEE4A4FA4C61421214B9F40",
            "canReassign":true,
            "boundUserName":"",
            "ETag":"14315.0",
            "stepDeadlineStatus":0,
            "stepName":"020 Autuacao",
            "workObjectNumber":"9E1DCCF25AEE4A4FA4C61421214B9F40",
            "caseFolderId":"{008DB74F-0000-C516-B965-5D1351219C0E}",
            "queueName":"SPLN_Autuacao",
            "lockedById":0,
            "columns":{
                "F_StepName":"020 Autuacao",
                "SPLN_resultout":"COMPLETE: ",
                "F_CreateTime":"2015-09-10T13:58:38Z",
                "F_Subject":"Fluxo Autuacao",
                "SPLN_funcmode":"PR_ELABORACAO:FN_ST_ELABORACAO",
                "SPLN_IDDocumento":"1098858",
                "SPLN_itemkey":"620007",
                "SPLN_itemtype":"SPL",
                "SPLN_actid":null,
                "SPLN_Natureza":"Projeto de lei"
            }
        },
        ...
    ],
    ...
}
```

However, if I try to query for a element - let´s say when SPLN_itemkey equals to 620007 - I tried to use a URL such as described [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/pt-br/SSNW2F_5.2.0/com.ibm.p8.pe.dev.doc/rest/rest_ref.htm#rest_ref__Queue_Elements).

```
[ECM SERVER]/CaseManager/P8BPMREST/p8/bpm/v1/queues/SPLN_Autuacao/workbaskets/Autuacao/queueelements?cp=CP1&filters=[SPLN_itemkey=620006]
```

I get This error message:

```
{
    "msg":"filenet.pe.rest.VWRESTException",
    "UnderlyingDetails":{
        "Causes":[
            "Invalid filters parameter.\n[FNRPE0450100011E] Invalid filter name",
            "Invalid filters parameter.\n[FNRPE0450100011E] Invalid filter name",
            "[FNRPE0450100011E] Invalid filter name"
        ]
    },
    "stack": "filenet.pe.rest.handlers.QueueElements$FiltersParam.parseFilters(QueueElements.java:458)\r\n\tfilenet.pe.rest.handlers.QueueElements.onGet(QueueElements.java:357)\r\n\tfilenet.pe.rest.P8BPMRESTServlet.doMethod(P8BPMRESTServlet.java:714)\r\n\t",
    "UserMessage":{
        "UniqueId":"FNRPE0450100011E",
        "Severity":"ERROR",
        "Text":"[FNRPE0450100011E] Invalid filter name"
    }
}
```

According the message, I am using a invalid filter name. So I tried make `filters=[itemkey=620006]` instead `filters=[SPLN_itemkey=620006]`. However I get the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the problem was not in the url. It was necessary first create a query in the ECM server to this URL worked.

Comment: accept your answer so that we would know it worked for you